# how to style the active link with inner span?

Tags: css

I want to set the colour for the active link. My links have the inner span like the following.

`<a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a>`

I have style it like the following but it did not work.

```
a:active span{
  color:yellow;
}
```

What css rule should I write for this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS are both valid (maybe not best practice - why the `<span>` ?) - what result are you expecting ?

Comment: I want to set the color of the link to yellow when index.php display.

Comment: the `:active` selector is only active when the link is being clicked on ... try using `:visited` -> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes

Comment: Or use a class for the currently active page (using PHP)

Answer (score 2):

The correct CSS is as follows. You should replace the `=` with a `:`.

```
a:active span {
    color: yellow;
}
```

### Edit

This is a response to the comment

> I want to set the color of the link to yellow when index.php display

This is not what `:active` does. This text is taken from w3.org. ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes )

> The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.

If you want to style the page that is currently being viewed you have to do that server side.

Comment: I posted this answer before you edited your post and before that edit this was what was wrong.

Comment: @Filip I kinda figured that, since when i posted my answer it was correct :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, its valid, but maybe you expect it to do something else then what it does. :active is not the selector for the menu item you selected or something, like the menu item you selected is yellow on the page after as a #current link or something.

Something else:

Note: :active MUST come after :hover (if present) in the CSS definition in order to be effective!